# Display all values of Hashtable through button

Tags: c#, winforms, hashtable

Okay so I'm trying to display multiple values in hashtable through my button. But it keeps on showing me the first value but not the others.

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    Hashtable Info = new Hashtable();

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string a = textBox1.Text;
        string b = textBox2.Text;
        Info.Add(a,b);
       label4.Text = a + " " + b;
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (DictionaryEntry DE in Info)
        {
            label4.Text = ""+ DE.Key +DE.Value; //this only shows the first added value. How do I show the remaining values?
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because each iteration of the loop *replaces* the previous value in the text. You can fix this by clearing out the text before going into the loop, and using `+=` instead of `=`:

```
label4.Text += " "+ DE.Key +DE.Value
```

A better approach would be to use `string.Join` for this:

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    label4.Text = string.Join(
        ", "
    ,   Info.Select(p => string.Format("{0}-{1}", p.Key, p.Value))
    );
}
```

Comment: You would also need to blank the text outside the loop.

Comment: or assign a local variable outside the loop and use the `+=` operator overload then assigne it to label4.Text

Comment: label4.Text += " "+ DE.Key +DE.Value works but its repeating the second value twice. How can I stop that?

Comment: @samjohal Did you add `label4.Text = ""` before the `foreach` loop?

Comment: Oh k now it worked. But how come label4.Text = "" stops repeating it?

Comment: @samjohal It clears out the old value that was there when you clicked the button.

Comment: Yes!! Now I got it. Thanks for your help. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you don't keep changing label4.Text in the loop, but build a string in the loop and change it once at the end.  Something like:

```
        StringBuilder allEntries = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (DictionaryEntry DE in Info)
        {
            allEntries.Append(DE.Key);
            allEntries.Append(DE.Value);
        }
        label4.Text = allEntries.ToString();
```

[I edited an earlier version of the code that didn't compile.]

KC

Comment: This gives an error saying Cannot convert type string to System.Text.StringBuilder